# What is ExchangeStrategies in Spring Framework API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have recently started spring Framwork and I found ExchangeStrategies and I am curious to know that what is it.

sample code that I have found

```
   final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(150000))
                .build();
```

Thanks in advance :)